# How can I install thrift with luarocks?

Tags: lua, thrift

I am trying to use Thrift from within Lua language. I am trying to install the required libs using luarocks.

luarocks install thrift

returns error!

luarocks search thrift

returns no result!

Is there any luaforge (luarocks) package for Apache Thrift?

Comment: this is no competition who writes the shortest sentences. don't you think it would make sense to at least share the error message you get? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Thrift isn't available from the normal luarocks.org rocks repository, but through the Torch rocks repository. So if you want to install the Thrift library using Luarocks you need to add the Torch rocks repository to your Luarocks configuration.

To do this, locate the `cfg.lua` file in your Luarocks installation. This is different depending on the OS and the settings you used when you installed Luarocks. Mine is located in `/usr/local/etc/luarocks/`, for example.

Once you have located that file, open it and locate the `rocks_servers` variable declaration and add the string `"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torch/rocks/master"` to the list. Luarocks will be able to install the Thrift library (amongst other useful libraries, see [this](https://github.com/torch/rocks)).

**Important note: Torch, and thus Torch libraries, assume a LuaJIT interpreter**

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But it is not Thrift for lua! It is libthrift which differs from original Apache thrift!

Comment: Oops, well I'm going to leave my answer up just in case people with that issue come to this question. To my knowledge (and my github and google search) there is no rockspec out for the Apache Thrift Lua library. You are going to have to download the library from [here](https://github.com/apache/thrift) under `/lib/lua`. You'll need autotools to configure and compile the library.